# Firebase Auth: getCurrentUser from different Activities?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app with a login screen. Now, i just want to get the DisplayName of the user which is signed in in another Activity. How can I get this name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getCurrentUser()`:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, getEmail or etc
    String name = user.getDisplayName();   

    Log.d("TAG" + name) // the name ...
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Answer (score 0):

Using **SharedPreferences** or **Bundle** you can get it.

```
 private void onAuthSuccess(FirebaseUser currentUser) {

        userId = currentUser.getUid();
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        if (currentUser.getDisplayName() != null){
            editor.putString("userName", currentUser.getDisplayName());
        } else if (currentUser.getEmail() != null){
            editor.putString("useremail", currentUser.getEmail());
        }

        editor.putString("userId", currentUser.getUid());
        editor.commit();
    }
```

**Another Activity you can get it below**

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  
    String displayUser = sharedPref.getString("userName",null);
    String displayEmail = sharedPref.getString("useremail",null);
```

Comment: @Lars Dubrau please check it my answer if you have any issues let me know